# Vuepress - any way to compile/bulk-validate page markdown contents?

Tags: validation, vuepress

Let's take some markdown

```
This `<goodtag>` is  OK 

This <badtag> is not.
```

In Typora, a mac markdown editor, this renders as:

[image]

In Macdown:

[image]

In both editors, the problem is localized, the rest of the contents after `badtag` appears normally.

However, in Vuepress, things don't work at all and the page is all blank except for its title.

```
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 

  Errors compiling template:

  tag <badtag> has no matching end tag.

  1  |  
  2  |  <ContentSlotsDistributor :slot-key="$parent.slotKey"><p>This <code>&lt;goodtag&gt;</code> is  OK</p>
  3  |  <p>This <badtag> is not.</p>
```

I understand that `<badtag>` is going to cause a problem with Vuepress and why.  But I am not writing this as an individual page, I am pushing lots of existing markdown contents into a Vuepress directory.  The overall Vuepress dev build doesn't complain, this only shows as a problem when I navigate to that particular page, find it all blank and look at the JS console.

I already have a Python batch that performs transformations on the local markdown (for example, pushing local file system images into `.vuepress/public` with the appropriate URLs.  Can I catch these errors, by having the batch call Vuepress itself to pre-validate content?

Is there any way for me to run a "node vuepress compile /foo/mymarkdown.md" at an individual page, check its return code and notify me that something needs fixing on that page?

As I wrote this I think maybe an `npm run build` to build the actual distribution would do the trick.  Maybe.  But I need to isolate it on a page by page basis, not bulk-run it on 500+ pages at a time and then pick out all the errors.

Comment: There isn't the feature for individual compiles, but you can build some script using [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) for compile individual files. The Vuepress uses the markdown-it to render makdown files: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#advanced-configuration

Comment: @GabrielWillemann  Good suggestion. But I doubt that it would work, although it did get me to think more my case.  `markdown-it` is most likely only involved at the markdown->html phase.  but the error I am getting is a JS&Vue compile error - the html is ready and probably includes any embedded html as well.  the problem is that Vue is pretty aggressive about grabbing anything that looks like a non-standard html tag (and throwing hard compile errors when it's not happy).  I've seen this before in Vue apps, not just Vuepress.  basically, markdown-it is very likely **not** to care about this.

Comment: Server side rendering might help, combined with a Selenium or the like headless *browser* load.  By that point, maybe a straight follow all links strategy based on something like Selenium, or better, Cypress might work too.